# ¿ocultar E_NOTICE, E_WARNING, E_DEPRECATED o programar bajo E_ALL?

Tags: php

Llevo año y medio programando en php y justamente llevo 1 semana programando bajo `error_reporting (E_ALL)` cubriendo los errores de variables/arrays indefinidos y entre otros problemitas "menores", pero ¿es necesario omitir los `E_NOTICE`, `E_WARNING` y `E_DEPRECATED`, o es recomendable programar arrojándome todos los errores (`E_ALL`)?

Comment: Yo cuando estoy desarrollando siempre tengo puesto que muestre todos los errores, por si acaso... incluso los warnings y notices. Quiero saber todo lo que anda mal en mi código. EDIT: muchas veces uso un gestor de errores personalizado, pero aún así, generalmente lo tengo puesto en modo mostrar todos los errores.

Comment: ¿como es eso de "gestor de errores personalizado"?

Comment: Crear una clase o manejador de errores personalizada, para poder gestionarlos mejor. La forma más básica la puedes encontrar aquí:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Los errores no son para evadirlos, sino para enfrentarlos y para preveerlos. Es como en la vida: un programa nunca será maduro, ni seguro, si no sabe manejar los errores. Es responsabilidad de quien programa escribir un código que esté controlado en todo momento, que haga lo que el programador le diga. Por ejemplo, si lanzas una consulta a la base de datos, tú no puedes escribir el código pensando que siempre funcionará. En algo tan simple pueden fallar muchas cosas: la conexión, la sintaxis de la consulta, que la consulta venga sin datos. El código debe ser programado para manejar todo eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe desarrollar con el máximo nivel de información de errores activado. Con esto podremos evitar una parte importante de posibles errores en producción, ya que incluso *warnings* y *notificaciones* que podrían no hacer fallar la aplicación en un momento dado van a llenar el *log de errores* del servidor lo que nos puede hacer más complicado encontrar errores en un momento dado u ofrecer una información que debería estar oculta en caso de poder ser accedido.
Así mismo. se desaconsejan prácticas como el uso de **@** delante de funciones para silenciar errores durante la ejecución.

Se debe programar con el mínimo de errores y esto supone que debemos evitarlos en lo posible y si los hay tratar de encontrarlos y corregirlos en etapas tempranas del desarrollo. Además de todo esto, se deben usar uno o más sistemas que permitan su control durante el ciclo de vida de la aplicación, como control de excepciones, sistema de logs, feedbacks, etc.